# axios.post gets denied but axios config gets accepted

Tags: javascript, get, axios

I'm making a POST request and I'm wondering why  axios.post is getting denied with error 401 while the same requests succesfully works if I use the axios config syntax.

This here gets denied with 401

```
  const response = await axios.post(url, {
  headers: {
    "X-Csrf-Token": csfrToken,
    Cookie: cookies.join(";")
  },
  data: {
    "Name": "airpods",
    "BuyerPartyID": "1000084",
    "zkRelatedContract_KUT": "626"
  }
});
```

And this gets accepted

```
    const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "X-Csrf-Token": csfrToken,
        Cookie: cookies.join(";")

    },
    data: {
        "Name": "airpods",
        "BuyerPartyID": "1000084",
        "zkRelatedContract_KUT": "626"
    }
})
```

Comment: shouldn't it be the otherway around, like `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])` ?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't configuring the request correctly. And the first option for post is the data itself, not the axios config. Have them swapped

Docs: https://github.com/axios/axios

```
 const response = await axios.post({url,
    {
    "Name": "airpods",
    "BuyerPartyID": "1000084",
    "zkRelatedContract_KUT": "626"
  },
  headers: {
    "X-Csrf-Token": csfrToken,
    Cookie: cookies.join(";")
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but  your solution gets denied with error 400, if I remove the data key it works tho (see my post further down below).

Comment: @JangoCG My bad!  But the idea was to swap the params :) Actually I went by the older syntax of axios.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `URL`,
  data :{},
  headers: {}
})

Answer (score 0):

You should swap the order in `post()`

`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, thanks for the helpful replies.

```
let response = await axios.post( url,
         {
            "Name": "airpods",
            "BuyerPartyID": "1000084",
            "zkRelatedContract_KUT": "626"
         },
        {
            headers: {
                "X-Csrf-Token": csfrToken,
                Cookie: cookies.join(";")
              },
         } 
      );
```